# Observable result constructor not called

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to run some code everytime a observable has a result type of MessageResult

Calling the service

```
this.campaignService.postCreate(this.authService, {
            CampaignCode: this.campaignCode,
            Year: this.year,
            StartDt: this.startDt,
            EndDt: this.endDt,
            InhouseDt: this.inhouseDt,
            MailDt: this.mailDt,
            MarketingId: this.marketingId,
            TemplateId: this.templateId
        }).subscribe(x => {
           console.log(x.text);
           //this doesn't event work -> x.fire; or x.fire();
});
```

Then the service

```
  postCreate(refAuthService, formResult: any): Observable<MessageResult> {
    return refAuthService.PostWithHeader("http://api.positive.local:38880/api/campaign/postcreate", formResult)
        .map(this.extractData).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

The messageResult

```
import { ToastsManager } from 'ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class MessageResult {
    constructor(
        public text: string,
        public type: string,
        public title: string,
        private toastr: ToastsManager) {
        this.fire();
    }

    fire() {
        console.log("that");
        if (this.type == 'error')
            this.toastr.error(this.text, this.title, {
                toastLife: 2500
            });
        else if (this.type == 'success')
            this.toastr.success(this.text, this.title, {
                toastLife: 2500
            });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("this");
    }

}
```

Neither this nor that was shown in the console.

The goal is to have every observable result that is a MessageResult to fire the message without additional coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is to try moving the `fire()` function to the service and have it take a parameter of type `MessageResult` and add another `map` function to your observable:

```
postCreate(refAuthService, formResult: any): Observable<MessageResult> {
    return refAuthService.PostWithHeader("http://api.positive.local:38880/api/campaign/postcreate", formResult)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .map(data => this.fire(data)   //<-- ADD THIS
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

This way, the `fire` function will fire when the observable is subscribed to and does not require additional coding in the component consuming the service.

Generally, I use interfaces to map data from observables instead of classes, though classes can work fine.  But I keep any logic confined to a component and not a data model.

Comment: Wish I didn't have to do map and including a function across all my services but this will have to do Thanks